# Meaning and related period of this symbol (art antiques)

Tags: character-identification

I did some research of some of the characters which got me to that of Qianglong ceramics, but not all of the characters are identical. Does someone know the meaning of this four character "watermark" and the date to which it belongs?

Picture I found in a fast search:

[image]

The unidentified characters:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

乾隆年製 - Qianlong, the 6th Emperor of the Qing dynasty. He ruled the kingdom for 60 years since crowning in 1735. The period under his rule is usually called "乾隆年間". The seal identifies the item that was made/produced (製) sometimes in that period.

澳門製造 - Made in Macau.